# Calculation the sum of long long int

Tags: c++, c++14

> (calculating the sum of long long numbers)

whenever I input a long long number the program returns always -1 or -2 anyone knows why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int n,i;
long long x1,x2,s;
do{
cin>>n;
}while(n<1);
long long t1[n];
long long t2[n];
string ch1,ch2;
i=0;
do{
    do{
        scanf("%lld %lld", &x1, &x2);   
        ch1=to_string(x1);
        ch2=to_string(x2);
    }while((ch1.length()>pow(10,5)) || (ch2.length()>pow(10,5)));
t1[i]=x1;
t2[i]=x2;
i++;
}while(i<n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    s=t1[i]+t2[i];
    cout<<s<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

can't find a solution please help! and thx in advance!

> example input:
>
> 1
>
> 14444444444444444111115556
>
> 55656464684646464646647676
>
> output
>
> -2

//edit:

Is there a way to calculate the sum of 100000 :) decimal digits numbers like the ones in the example using standard libraries ?

Comment: Could you paste up an example with the UI inputs replaced with constants?

Comment: Regarding the input loop: how likely do you think it is that a `long long` (most likely 64 bits) will have more than 100,000 decimal digits?

Comment: is there a way to calculate sum of numbers like that? is there other libraries or anything?

Comment: @medamine Look into GMP : https://gmplib.org

Comment: @JesperJuhl can you please provide more informations about this library and how one can declare a 100 000 digit ?

Comment: Just read the documentation on the website.

Comment: @molbdnilo then how to calculate 100000+ decimal digits numbers.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I can't read all of that 148 pages

Comment: *Your* problem. *Not* mine.

Comment: @JesperJuhl ^_^ thx anyway!

Comment: @medamine Don't use numerical types. Use collections of individual digits. Add them the way you were taught when you were little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamental integral types such as `long long` have limited range that they can represent. If a calculation causes results in a larger result than can be represented, it will overflow. Signed integer overflow has undefined behaviour in C++.

It is possible to represent an infinite range of numbers (in theory, memory limits the practice) by using an array of integers to represent different parts of the number. This technique is called *arbitrary precision arithmetic*.

There is no implementation of arbitrary precision types in the C++ standard library, so either you must implement one yourself, or you can use a library implemented by others.